# spilt string only when multiple spaces occurs in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

split string only when two or more spaces occurs.

```
string="Talk Talk  Walk Walk         sell sell";
```

Expected Result after split:

```
string[0]='Talk Talk';
string[1]='Walk Walk';
string[2]='sell sell';
```

Thanks

Comment: Prepare for a lot of regex solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `/\s{2,}/`, which means that, if there are 2 or more white space characters, split the string there.

```
myString="Talk Talk  Walk Walk         sell sell";
console.log(myString.split(/\s{2,}/));
```

**Output**

```
[ 'Talk Talk', 'Walk Walk', 'sell sell' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if not using RegEx.

```
var myString = "Talk Talk  Walk Walk         sell sell";
var result = myString.split("  ");

for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (result[i] === "") {
        result.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

The result variable will have an array of split values.

Comment: You might want to trim the resultant elements. `"a   b".split(two_spaces)` yields `["a", " b"]`. Then, you'd have to remove empty elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str="Talk Talk  Walk Walk         sell sell";
var s = str.replace(/ {2,}/g,";").split(';');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple way:**

```
var x = str.split(" +");
```